# Load a Text File using Javascript

Tags: html

New to programming.

I am trying to load a text file (say c:\test.txt") using javascript with the following code. I want to specify a fixed path for the file. I do not want to choose the file from the directory. I want to load it automatically, so that I can use it further to add some more text in a new line.

All responses and help acknowledged in advance.

```
<html>
<body>
<table><tr><td>File to Load:<input type="file" id="fileToLoad"><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load File</button><td></tr>
</table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function loadFileAsText()
{var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To load content you to use load() of jQuery which lets to fetch contents dynamically and can be added to any div or span.

There is an example for callback function after successful load on content.

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$( "#result" ).load( "test.txt" );

});

</script>

<script>

$( "#result" ).load( "test.txt", function() {
alert( "Load was performed." );
});

</script>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Gaurav. However, I am new to programming and do not know JQuery. I want to use this or similar code to load a file on my laptop and add some text later.

Comment: Its my pleasure to help.Let me know if you any query regarding this.